# Open new page with tickets from a selected event

Tags: php

I am trying to make an registration site.
At the moment I have different tables like user, event, ticket, …
Each event can have multiple tickets.

When someone login on the site, the upcoming events are directly showed.
This data comes out of the event table. (like event ID, eventSDate, eventEDate, eventDescription…)
On each event block, there is also displaying a button.
(see code)

```
<?php 

                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM event WHERE  eventSDate  >= NOW() ORDER by eventSDate ASC");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))  { 



                        echo '<tr>
                                <td><h8>'. $row['eventName'] .'</h8></td><br>

                                <td><h4><strong>Begin:</strong> &nbsp; ',date("d.m.Y", strtotime ($row['eventSDate'])),' &nbsp; ', date('H:i', strtotime ($row['eventSTime'])).' hr.<h4></td>
                                <td><h4><strong>Einde:</strong> &nbsp; ',date("d.m.Y", strtotime ($row['eventEDate'])),' &nbsp; ', date('H:i', strtotime ($row['eventETime'])).' hr.<h4></td>
                                <td><h4>'. $row['eventDescription'] .'</h4></td>
                                <td><h4>'. $row['eventID'] .'  <input name="book" type="button" value="Ga verder" /></h4></td>
                                <br><br>
                            </tr>';
                    }

            ?
```

Now I like to do following: when someone click on the button, a new page 'tickets.php' should open where the user see all the tickets that are available for that specific event.
In the ticket table, also the eventID field is stored.

How can I reach this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a form to send eventID to tickets.php so that you can display only tickets for that event.
Your html becomes the following:

```
<td><h4>'. $row['eventID'] .'  
        <form action="tickets.php" method="get">
            <input name="book" type="submit" value="Ga verder" />
            <input type="hidden" name="eventID" value="'.$row['eventID'].'">
        </form>
    </h4></td>
```

Now, in your tickets.php you have the your eventID stored in the $_GET array, so you can do a query like that

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE eventID = ".$_GET['eventID'] ." ORDER by eventSDate ASC");
```

Comment: should set your button type to "submit"

Comment: Works Perfect !!

Thanks to help me out here !!

Grtz Benny

Comment: I didn't included an anti-SQL injection filter, be sure to include that if you want to go live with your Website or it will be vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Where you're printing the button, add a data attribute to store the event ID..

```
<td><h4>'. $row['eventID'] .'  <input data-eid="'. $row['eventID'] .'" name="book" type="button" value="Ga verder" /></h4></td>
```

Then add some javascrtipt to make it act like a link (example uses jQuery for simplicity)

```
$("input[name='book']").click(function(){
    window.location = "tickets.php?eid="+$(this).data('eid');
});
```

Now you can create "tickets.php" and grab the event id from the query string, like this

```
$eventID = $_GET['eid'];
```

use something  like this..

```
"select * from tickets where eventID = $eventID"
```